# publisher not shown in task manager c#.net winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, taskmanager

Is it normal for C#.net winforms app for the publisher not to be shown in task manager?

I published My App using this:

[image]

These are the properties:

[image]

This is my code so that my app will run on start up:

```
       public Main() {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            reg.SetValue("Power Monitor", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        }
```

When I open the task manager and look at the startup, this is what it looks like:

[image]

The publisher is not here :(

But when I go to the control panel, the publisher name is there:

[image]

Did I do something wrong in the publishing process?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you are running the installer at startup.  In the Winforms project, edit AssemblyInfo.cs, pick a non-empty string for the [AssemblyCompany] attribute.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Let me accept your answer @HansPassant